# How do I extract images from html files in a directory?

Tags: python, html, image, beautifulsoup

This is a followup to this question:  [How do I parse every html file in a directory for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608683/how-do-i-parse-every-html-file-in-a-directory-for-images)
Essentially, I have a directory of html files each of which contain images  that I would like to save separately in the same directory.

After making the suggested changes to the program, I am still getting an error:

```
Image: theme/pfeil_grau.gif

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\gokalraina\Desktop\modfile.py", line 25, in <module>
  im = Image.open(image)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1956, in open
prefix = fp.read(16)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

This is the revised code (thanks to nightcracker) that I am using.

```
 import os, os.path
 import Image
 from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

  path = 'C:\Users\gokalraina\Desktop\derm images'

 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
      soup = bs(open(os.path.join(root, f)).read())
      for image in soup.findAll("img"):
        print "Image: %(src)s" % image
        im = Image.open(image)
        im.save(path+image["src"], "JPEG")
```

Comment: Please include the whole output up to that point, including the one for the `print "Image: %s" % image` bit.

Comment: I have added it; there was only one print before it broke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is passing a `BeautifulSoup.Tag` object to `Image.open`, but `Image.open` is expecting a path or a file object.  You can get the relative path to the image with `image["src"]`, so the code would be:

```
im = Image.open(image["src"])
```

However, that path is the same path written in the HTML file, which is probably a relative path starting from the HTML file's directory.  If so, joining `root` to `image["src"]` will get the absolute path for each image:

```
im = Image.open(os.path.join(root, image["src"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Image.open()` might not be able to handle remote files. You'd better download the images using `urllib` or `urllib2` module.

Comment: The html files are in a directory on my hard drive, not directly from the internet.

Comment: Then may be it can't handle File URI, try converting the links to local path first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977576/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-map-a-file-uri-to-os-path

Comment: What is a file URI, and what links would I need to convert?